# Aurelia Validation on dynamically built form

Tags: aurelia

I'm creating a custom element that dynamically generates a user input form.  So far it's working quite well, but I'm having problems setting up Aurelia-Validation on it and need some help.

**my-form.html**

```
<div class="form-group" repeat.for="control of controls">
  <label>${control.label}</label>
  <div>
    <compose containerless
      view-model="resources/elements/${control.type}/${control.type}" 
      model.bind="{'control': control, 'model': model, 'readonly': readonly}"
      class="form-control"></compose>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have several different `control.type`'s available and working (`my-textbox`, `my-dropdown`, `my-datepicker`) -- each of them is a custom element.  For instance:

**Example control (my-textbox.html)**

```
<template>
  <input type="text"
    class="form-control" 
    value.bind="model[control.bind] & validate">
</template>
```

**Parent view:**

```
<my-form controls.bind="controls" model.bind="model" if.bind="controls"></my-form>
```

**Parent view-model:**

```
controls = [
  {label: 'Username', type: 'my-textbox', bind: 'user_username'},
  {label: 'Status', type: 'my-dropdown', bind: 'user_status', enum: 'ActiveInactive', default: '(Choose)'},
  {label: 'Last_login', type: 'my-datepicker', bind: 'user_lastlogin', vc: 'date'}];

ValidationRules
  .ensure('user_username').required().minLength(1).maxLength(10)
  .ensure('user_status').required()
  .ensure('user_lastlogin').required()
  .on(this.model);
```

I'm getting the error **Error: A ValidationController has not been registered.  at ValidateBindingBehaviorBase.bind...**.  However, I only want one validator for the whole dynamically-built form, so I don't want to import validation in each of the controls.  What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually works to import the Validation Controller and related resources in the parent form, even though the `& validate` is attached to the child controls.

**Parent view-model**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ValidationControllerFactory, ValidationRules} from 'aurelia-validation';
import {BootstrapFormRenderer} from 'common/bootstrap-form-renderer';

@inject(Core, ValidationControllerFactory)
export class MyForm {
  constructor(validationControllerFactory) {
    this.validationCtrl = validationControllerFactory.createForCurrentScope();
    this.validationCtrl.addRenderer(new BootstrapFormRenderer());
  }
  setupValidator() {
    let rules = [];
    this.controls.map(control => {
      if (control.validation) {
        rules.push(ValidationRules.ensure(control.bind).required().rules[0]);
    }
    this.validationCtrl.addObject(this.modelEdit, rules);
  }
}
```